# Extend Facebook permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need a new permission for my application.
How can I extend (reask) permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible programmatically.

User has to "delete" that application from his privacy settings and retry again

Comment: this is surely possible, i just did it yesterday using the code i posted in my answer

Comment: genesis: that's absolutely not true.

Comment: @BenjaminNetter: in your code it is possible it'll just redirect yourself to FB, and it is possible that FB tells you that you are already registered. At least with PHPSDK

Answer (score 2):

Replace app_id, url of your app main script and add needed permissions (scope). Then place this string to browser and press Enter ;)
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Facebook Javascript SDK too:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_EN/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
    appId  : 'your app id',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
</script>

<script>
function askPermission() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            /* New permissions granted */
            var newAccessToken = response.session.access_token;
        }
    }, {perms:'email'});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

my application was asking for basic permission first then i changed it to ask for extended using below code in php:

```
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');


    if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
                    // Permission is granted!
                    // Do the related task
                    //$post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'Hello World!'));
                      $post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);

                } else {
                    // We don't have the permission
                    // Alert the user or ask for the permission!
                    echo "Click Below to Enter!";
                    header( "Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream")) );
                }
```

the else part asks for permission if user hasn't granted extended permission yet.